# How to find child and disable checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, foreach, kendo-ui

If one parent is selected I want to disable other parents and their child. How can I achieve this task. I am using AngularJS for this implementation.

So far tried code..

HTML

```
<div id="treeViewDisplay4" class="dropdown-menu multi-level"
    ng-style="nonPersistentProcess.geoLocationStyle">
    <div kendo-tree-view="geoLocationTree"
        k-data-source="geoLocationDataSource"
        options="geoLocationTreeOptions"
        k-on-expand="onGeoExpand(kendoEvent)"
        k-rebind="nonPersistentProcess.selectedTypeGEO">
    </div>
</div>
```

main.js

```
 var getChildren = geoLocation.children;
 $.each(geoLocation.children,function(index,location) {
   var data = geoLocation.children.data;
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
   for (var i =0; i<data.length; i++) {
     if (data[i] !== geoLocation.id) {
       $scope.geoLocationTree.expand(".k-item");
       $scope.geoLocationTree.collapse(".k-item");
       var disableChildren = 'disabled' + data.id;
       // Get the model
       var model = $parse(disableChildren);
       // Assigns a value to it
       model.assign($scope, true);
       }
     }
   });
```

data.js

```
[
    {
        "id": 67000,
        "text": "Americas",
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 5677,
                "text": "Anguilla",
                "items": null
            },
            {
                "id": 5678,
                "text": "Antarctica",
                "items": null
            },
            {
                "id": 5679,
                "text": "Antigua And Barbuda",
                "items": null
            }
        ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML as well.

Comment: Also, I would suggest using better tags for the question.  For example, I suggest replacing the [tag:for-loop] with [tag:kendo-ui]

Comment: You're 100% in the jQuery mindset here.  Use `ng-disabled` along with a variable in your controller to do this and you'll save about 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution for above question, I implemented loop isnide the loop that did the magic...thanks for the help

```
if (geoLocation.id === 5657){
              var getParent = geoLocation.parent();
              $.each(geoLocation.parent(),function(index,location) {
                if (location.id !== geoLocation.id) {
                  $.each(location._childrenOptions.data.items,function(index,child){
                    var disableChildId = 'disabled' + child.id;
                    var model = $parse(disableChildId);
                      model.assign($scope, false);
                  })
                  var disableItemId = 'disabled' + location.id;
                  // Get the model
                  var model = $parse(disableItemId);
                  // Assigns a value to it
                  model.assign($scope, false);
                }
              });
            }
```